# Angularjs set custom header parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In angularjs i must set a custom header for a POST

So i make:

```
var config = { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'TenantCode': 'MYTENANT', 'LoginType': 'PASSW' };
```

So i execute the post

```
$http.post(urlBase + '/Token', data, config)
```

Anyway when i inspect the request i have

```
OPTIONS /Token HTTP/1.1
Host: test.strokein.it
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:54599
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:54599/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

and i don't see my header parameter

Why? What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think your config needs to look something like this:

```
var config = { 
    headers : {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
        'TenantCode': 'MYTENANT', 
        'LoginType': 'PASSW' 
    }
};
```

Looking at [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage) specification of config.

Answer (score 0):

That is your preflight request.
You have a CORS problem because you are testing from `localhost` to `test.strokein.it`
Easy fix would be you upload your test script to your server.

But in general, browser will send one more request after it gets an OK CORS response from your server i.e.

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, OPTIONS, PUT'
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'
```

Then you should see your custom headers along with data on that POST request.

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS